# Images on admin backend not showing up

Tags: wp-admin, media, media-library

It was going alright with images a week ago! But recently when I noticed I found that image thumbnails in media library and in post editor were either not showing up or were just showing there file-names. I need to do a lot of work with images, so I have a custom column on post admin page that shows featured images of the post is showing that same behavior as media library. Here is Media library[image: Image 1]

and in Post editor [image: Image 2]

It is very important requirement to have images for site working. 
Can anyone provide suggestions, how to resolve this?

Comment: Are the images exist on the server?

Comment: yes sir, on sameserver

Comment: Have you checked it in more than one browser?

Comment: yes, I have checked in all browsers.

Comment: Even though the images don't display, you should see the URLs in the source. Are those correct? If not, what is wrong with them?

Comment: Actually,there was problem with a plugin. I deactivated all and them activated each one by one and found the root cause was dynamic image resizer plugin was casing this.